# How to perform a rebase onto a specific commit?

Tags: git, version-control, rebase, git-rebase

Gitlovers, I have one issue.

Several commits ago, after last merging dev branch into master, I forgot to switch back to the dev branch. And I continued to make commits into the wrong branch: master - which should be back to where the merge happened. How do I swap the branches so it makes the situation as if I switched back to the dev branch after I merged it into master?

I tried with rebase:

`git checkout master; git rebase dev;`
and
`git checkout master; git rebase --onto dev;` doing something weird for me..

[image]

sorry for my horrible english (corrections are welcome) :-)

Comment: this diagram was wrong. the right-most branch was dev. Master was pointing to the left-most high-lighted commit. Hence the confusion, mass edits and comment over-load!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A general solution that will also work for more complex scenarios where history isn't linear. **Ensure that you are on the master branch**, then:

```
git rebase --preserve-merges --onto master^2 master dev
```

What must have happened for you to get in the situation is that you did this:

1. checked out master
2. merged dev
3. checked out dev
4. merged master (!!!)
5. continued to develop on dev

the mistake is step 4. This is called a back merge and should be avoided - although some trunk based workflows benefit from it.

Comment: Thanks for answer. After experiments with recipe from xsazz i have this now - http://joxi.ru/GxyqRYH . How improve this?

Comment: looks like you have the commits you want under dev and master is where it should be.. what do you want to do?

Comment: Same [picture](http://joxi.ru/A03KcOL) without labels and with my visual explanation. I want that first commit from green branch was inherits from last commit blue branch.

Comment: Thanks of course.. but how resolve issue which above this comment?

Comment: I'll add more comments to the steps

Comment: failure in the second step: $ git rebase --onto dev master~20 master;
fatal: Needed a single revision;
invalid upstream master~20;

Comment: are you in the same spot as when you initially asked the question?

Comment: Adam, maybe I will give you access to my repo? This will be more simple for you to figure out..

Comment: sure. why not.. adymitruk on github

Comment: but I won't be able to help you with conflict resolutions.

Comment: $ git cherry-pick master~20..master; fatal: ambiguous argument 'master~20..master': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.; 
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions

Comment: master is really early on .. not sure if you sent me the right repo

Comment: it looks like you want to do the vice-versa.. rebase dev onto master

Comment: https://github.com/milushov/divers
I see you in collaborators section of admin panel

Comment: I don't see your latest commits.. you didn't push any of that history up. It says last updated 14 hours ago

Comment: https://github.com/milushov/divers/network or see dev branch; my local repo is up-to-date

Comment: I see.. you want all dev to be on top of the "falling stars" commit, right?

Comment: yep, on top "falling stars" commit

Comment: yet another stupid question: why new "visual" (i know that it is the same branch) branch is green? I thought that it will be as a continuation of blue branch

Comment: it does that because the lineage is not guaranteed to have been generated by a branch. In git, who is a parent is more important than what branch that action occurred on.

Comment: I would try the solution yourself first. You will have me as the committer. Not sure if you want that :)

Comment: then force push to get rid of my commits

Comment: oh, that's ok; what i should do better pull or re-clone?

Comment: reclone is easiest.. but do it in a second directory just in case

Comment: no problem, enjoy! Google "branch per feature" to learn more about branching models ;)

Comment: ow, i know! (i read about git-flow pattern) btw this is just a start of project and i still building scaffold.. oh, my english, i feel how its terrible =D

Answer (score 2):

You're basically moving a bunch of commits from the master branch back onto the dev branch. I had a similar situation trying to move commits from one topic branch to another. The `--onto` switch of the `rebase` command does this. I don't want to repeat my whole blog post here but this is where I detailed what I did - http://nibrahim.net.in/2012/01/09/moving_topic_branches_in_git.html

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
$ git checkout dev
$ git merge master
$ get checkout master
$ get reset --hard [the revision you want to return]
```

Comment: How to make merge by NOT recursive mode? (recursive enabled by default) Maybe exist some keys for this..?

Comment: @roma If master is just changes on top of dev, the merge should have been a fast forward.  Either you have merge configured not to fast-forward via the `merge.ff` option in your `~/.gitconfig` or `.git/config` (see the git-config man page) OR you've made changes to dev. Your illustration says you haven't made changes to dev.

Comment: the original diagram did not represent what the repo contained.

Answer (score 1):

No need to rebase or merge.  Branches are nothing more than labels on commits.  You can move the labels using `git reset`.  Despite its name, `reset` is really the `move labels around` command.

1. `git tag master dev.target` Store a tag where dev should go before we move master.
2. `git checkout master`
3. `git reset --hard dev` Move master to where dev is.
4. `git checkout dev`
5. `git reset --hard dev.target` Move dev to where master was.
6. `git tag -d dev.target` Remove the placeholder.

You can do it without the tag using the commit id, but the tag is a big of insurance in case you screw things up.  This is essentially the "undo a commit, making it a topic branch" recipe from the [git-reset man page](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-reset.html), except your topic branch already exists.

Alternatively, since you just want to swap the branches, you can rename them!

1. `git branch -m master dev.mv`
2. `git branch -m dev master`
3. `git branch -m dev.mv dev`

The down side is if they have any upstream tracking it will be incorrect.  You'd have to go into `.git/config` to correct it.

Comment: That's what I thought at first too. however, he does need to rebase/cherry-pick a range. The original question did not present what was the reality of the repo. The ancestor of the latest range of commits needs to be changed. You can't do this with reset. The parent of the first commit made mistakenly on dev when dev was pointing to the wrong place needs to be changed.

Comment: you can see the eternal struggle in the comments to my answer :)